# NSdictionary element from xml

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

i have a situation I am getting data from the server as xml, i converted that data into NSDictionary using https://github.com/Insert-Witty-Name

MY xml is like

```
<Game>
      <userid></userid>
      <name></name>
      <friendId></friendId>
      <friendName></friendName>
</Game>
```

the value Game and all other items can change, so first I need to find out the name of the first element that is a game =>

I converted this through above Library now I am getting as

```
 xmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Game><userid>12</userid><userName>ben</userName><friendId>41</friendId><friendName>Ben1</friendName></Game>"];

NSDictionary *dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:xmlString error:nil];

NSString *string;
string = [dict objectForKey:@"Game"];
NSLog(@"name is :%@",string);
```

and the output is

```
{
friendId = 41;
friendName = Ben1;
userName = ben;
userid = 12;
}
```

I need to find out the root element name of xml and how to access these values in NSDictionary with objectForKey

Comment: hope this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/1549311/857865

Comment: can you explain more your problem?

Comment: try string = [[dict objectForKey:@"Game"] objectForKey:@"userName"];

Comment: @DeepakSamuelRajan yeah i got the value , and can i find the root element name like Game, like it can be Login or any thing other too

Comment: I think what is happening here is nested dictionary is created and it acts same as NSDictionary

Comment: use Enumerator to iterate and find value based on the key

Comment: please click my answer below if this solved your query :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string = [[dict objectForKey:@"Game"] objectForKey:@"userName"];
```

use Enumerator to iterate and find value based on the key or
 `[[dict objectForKey:@"Game"] allKeys]` to get all keys

Comment: For Root took allKeys of the dict in an array and get the objectAtIndex 0. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you want the result to be `"ben"`, correct? Well, `[dict objectForKey:@"Game"];` is not an `NSString` but an `NSDictionary`. You get no error because there is no way for LLVM to check this at compile time, so it happily will build. The conversion to a string happens in the parsing into the format string `"%@"`. Instead, what you want is this:

```
string = [[dict objectForKey:@"Game"] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

**EDIT: Different question as becomes clear from the comments...**

Or do you rather need `"Game"`? In which case

```
NSString* rootName = [[dict allKeys] firstObject];
```

Will give you always the correct answer, since there always is only one root.

Answer (score 1):

If your xml can change

this:

```
<Game>
      <userid></userid>
      <name></name>
      <friendId></friendId>
      <friendName></friendName>
</Game>
```

becoming this:

```
<Status>
      <userid></userid>
      <name></name>
      <friendId></friendId>
      <friendName></friendName>
</Status>
```

then you have to dynamically find the dictionary keys, using the method allKeys

like this:

```
[dict allKeys]
```

on my first example the result will be: `["Game"]` and on the second: `["Status"]`

if you need the keys of the inner element just do like this:

```
[[dict objectForKey:@"Game"] allKeys]
```

this will return: `["userid","name","friendId", "friendName"]`

Comment: the inner values can also change, so i need to find the root element, so i will be able to know that the elements inside will be ....